# Why Cascading is also resizing the forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

User opens a child form, resizes it a little bit, then opens another form, and I am calling

```
this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Cascade);
```

when we are opening a child form. So yes it cascades them but also resizes them to some default size I do not know where it is getting it from. Yes I want the second form to be cascaded to the first form but No I do not want the size and location of the previous forms to be changed everytime we call this Cascade method.  What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That's what cascading is: it resizes them and lines them up in a step configuration.

If you just want to bring your other form to the top, you can try calling `myChildForm.Select();`

You can try to set the `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties equal to each form's `Size` before the cascade, and then restore them afterwards.

```
List<Size> minSizes = new List<Size>();
List<Size> maxSizes = new List<Size>();
for (int i = 0; i < this.MdiChildren.Count(); i++) {
  minSizes.Add(this.MdiChildren[i].MinimumSize);
  maxSizes.Add(this.MdiChildren[i].MaximumSize);
  this.MdiChildren[i].MinimumSize = this.MdiChildren[i].Size;
  this.MdiChildren[i].MaximumSize = this.MdiChildren[i].Size;
}

this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);

for (int i = 0; i < this.MdiChildren.Count(); i++) {
  this.MdiChildren[i].MinimumSize = minSizes[i];
  this.MdiChildren[i].MaximumSize = maxSizes[i];
}
```